# translate an snmpwalk without mibs

Tags: snmp, mib

I want to run snmpwalk without any MIB files and save the output to a .txt file.
The .txt file will be a bunch of numbers without any useful information, since I won't reference any MIB files.
Is there a way to use snmptranslate to load back in the .txt file while also referencing MIB files to convert the useless data into useful data?

Comment: No. SNMP is designed in a way that MIB documents play that role.

Comment: @LexLi thanks for the feedback.